# Upgraded to Windows 10 - Touchpad disables itself in control panel when plugging power off laptop

Tags: laptop, windows-10

I've upgraded to Windows 10.

When I unplug power from my laptop, touchpad stops working - it gets disabled in the control panel.

I can either plug the power back in to make it work, or plug a mouse and enable it back in the control panel.

What could be causing it ?

Comment: See the accepted answer in [Touchpad disables when on battery](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/touchpad-disables-when-on-battery/cbbc84d4-ce9c-47ff-88b2-8d8b75732d8f)

Answer (score 1):

It was just a simple matter of clicking "Update Drivers".

It's the first time it ever helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm haven't upgraded to Win10 yet, but I'm guessing that the PC is shutting it off to save power.  If you open the device manager, right click the touchpad and select 'properties'.  Then click the "Power Management" tab - if there's a check in the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power", uncheck it.

Comment: The option is unselected and grayed out

Comment: moreover: when I switch power plans (performance, power saver) the touchpad works in both of them.